# visual studio 2010 Character encoding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After creating a batch file in visual studio, I get an error when I run it about invalid characters. Does anyone know the default character encoding for txt files?

Comment: What line causes the problem?  What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default encoding for a text file in Visual Studio 2010 is UTF-8.

Therefore if you need to use ANSI I would recommend created the file outside of VS and then drag it to the project or add existing file to get it in the project.  From their VS will respect the file encoding.

Comment: My mistake, removed the reference from answer.  It doesn't change the answer from being correct though. :)

Comment: @Detroitpro question has been answered, did I miss something?